# Given $n$ points prove there is a polynomial with integer coefficients...

Tags: polynomials

For example if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of any degree and $p(x_1) = y_1$, $p(x_2) = y_2 \ldots$ where $x_k$ and $y_k$ are integers, how can I show that there is or there isn't a polynomial with integer coefficients going through the $n$ points?

$$p(2) = 4,~ p(6) = 6 ?$$

This was the original problem but I guess the general method is definitely sought for the answer.

Comment: Are $x_k,y_k$ integers?

Comment: Would anything change if they weren't?

Comment: Well. Yes. For instance if $p(1) = 1/2$, then clearly all the coefficients cannot be integers.

Comment: Then, I'll edit the question to make things clearer...

Comment: I don't understand the question. There ARE polynomials with integer coefficients. They do exist.

Comment: I guess the title doesn't state everything, I apologize for that...

Comment: Don't apologize --- edit!

Comment: @Gerry I did. And I removed the statement in my question which implied that title says it all. I've refined the question and I guess it's as clear as it can be now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that if the polynomial $P(x)$ has integer coeffients, then $6-2$ divides $P(6)-P(2)$.

Comment: +1. Very nice hint. Is this also a sufficient condition?

Comment: So, what you're saying is that for $n$ points I would need to check $\binom{n}{2}$ statements of that form if I wished to give an answer to the problem?

Comment: I guess the sufficient condition would be that the [divided difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences) are integers, which actually doesn't give much.

Comment: Is my understanding correct?
$p(x1) - p(x2) = a_{n}(x_{1}^n - x_{2}^n) + a_{n-1}(x_{1}^{n-1} - x_{2}^{n-1}) + \ldots + a_{1}(x_{1} - x_{2})$. To me, it seems that the difference is divisible by $(x_{1} - x_{2})$ regardless of the coefficients?

Comment: Divisible algebraically, yes, but the quotient needn't be an integer.

Comment: As a *polynomial* in two variables, yes. But that does not lead to any problem. There certainly is a polynomial with *rational* coefficients taking on any specified rational values $b_1,\dots,b_k$ at any specified points $a_1,\dots,a_k$.

Comment: Well, that clears things up. Thank you!

Comment: Without restriction to integers, you might look up the Lagrange Interpolation Theorem on Wikipedia.